# How should i handle reactJS dom manipulate (like scroll manipulation for example)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say i wanna do something pretty simple - upon a scroll change the title to fixed, is it ok to directly manipulate the dom? If not how else should i attack this?

for example:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    $('.content').bind('scroll',function(){
        if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 85) {
            $('#x').addClass('fixedTitle');

        } else {
            $('#x').removeClass('fixedTitle');

        }
    });
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
    $('.content').unbind("scroll");
}
```

And what if i wanna do something more complex, like understand which element is now at the view and give it a different class for example?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just attach events as needed and then call `setState` which will re-`render`? You shouldn't need jQuery to do this.

Comment: I know, that's why i said that this is a simple example. what if i wanna do more, like calculate the window size and change styles on the fly for example. or understand which element in a list is at the top of my scroll view and highlight it, or something like that.
I also think that this small dom manipulates are too costy to do with react, because why would i want to build the entire tree (lets say my component is an entire page) for just a small class change...

Comment: This seems like premature optimization right now. You can still use DOM APIs.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery tools and ReactJS don't always play very nicely together. If you manipulate the DOM, React's virtual representation of the DOM becomes out of sync with the actual DOM. If you're doing something small like changes the class to fixed, it probably won't be an issue.

If you are doing something bigger like understanding which element is now at the view (not entirely sure what you mean by that), then that element should probably be a react component.

Class names can also be changed in React, which could be done based on some kind of state. Check out this tool for doing something like that in your react code: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames.

Comment: Well i agree with you, and i know that in this small example i can use setState and render the class accordingly. But im not sure how to do something more complex like changing a highlighted row upon scroll for example, or something with more animations.